# How to change the header element

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have the following code snippet:

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filteredFiles"
    directory="#{controllerConfig['CYCLE'].params['SEMAPHORE_DIR']}"
    channel="semaphoreChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml" prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" cron ="#{controllerConfig['CYCLE'].controllerTimer}"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

...
Later in the flow in have a header enricher:

```
<int:header-enricher id="Channel Name Setter">
    <int:header name="channel.id" value="CYCLE"/>
    <int:header name="flow.id" overwrite="true" value="#{T(hu.telekom.fdl.util.TimeBasedUUIDGenerator).generateId()}"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

The problem is that although I used the overwrite="true" property the **flow.id** seems unchanged when the inbound-channel-adapter reads the second file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions with the form `#{...}` are evaluated once only, during context initialization. You need to use a runtime expression:

```
<int:header name="flow.id" overwrite="true" expresion="T(hu.telekom.fdl.util.TimeBasedUUIDGenerator).generateId()"/>
```

i.e. use `expression=` and remove the `#{}`.

You only need `overwrite="true"` if the header is already present on the inbound message to the enricher.